# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'."

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add a new textarea onClick for one of my buttons, however, I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'."**

HTML:

```
                <div class="form-group mt-2" id="we">
                    <label for="workField">Work Expereince</label>
                    <textarea
                        placeholder="Enter Text" 
                        class="form-control weField"
                        rows ="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="container text-center mt-2" id="weAddButton">
                        <button onclick="addNewWeField()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
function addNewWeField() {
    let newNode = document.createElement('textarea');
    newNode.classList.add('form-control');
    newNode.classList.add('weField');
    newNode.classList.add("mt-2");
    newNode.setAttribute("rows", 3);
    newNode.setAttribute('placeholder','Text Here')

    let weOb = document.getElementById("we");
    let weAddButtonOb = document.getElementsByTagName('weAddButton');

    weOb.insertBefore(newNode, weAddButtonOb);
}
```

Any help is appreicated!

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('weAddButton'); it will return htmlcollection of tags you need to tell number where you want to insert it  document.getElementsByTagName('weAddButton')[0];

Answer (score 0):

It's because "weAddButtonOb" is an HTMLCollection and not a Node. You probably want to get the id, instead of the tag name just like this:

```
function addNewWeField() {
   let newNode = document.createElement('textarea');
   newNode.classList.add('form-control');
   newNode.classList.add('weField');
   newNode.classList.add("mt-2");
   newNode.setAttribute("rows", 3);
   newNode.setAttribute('placeholder','Text Here')

   let weOb = document.getElementById("we");
   let weAddButtonOb = document.getElementById('weAddButton'); /*Return an Element*/

   weOb.insertBefore(newNode, weAddButtonOb);
```

}

You can also check the documentation about "insertBefore()" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore .

Comment: Implementing that code now gives the error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."
☁️ "Running fiddle"

Comment: this code is not working because `#WeAddButton` is not child of `#we`

Answer (score 0):

anyway this code should work

- #WeAddButton is not child of #we
- `.getElementsByTagName()` return `NodeList`

```js
function addNewWeField() {
    let newNode = document.createElement('textarea');
    newNode.classList.add('form-control');
    newNode.classList.add('weField');
    newNode.classList.add("mt-2");
    newNode.setAttribute("rows", 3);
    newNode.setAttribute('placeholder','Text Here')

    let weAddButtonOb = document.getElementById('weAddButton');

    weAddButtonOb.before(newNode);
}
```

```html
             <div class="form-group mt-2" id="we">
                    <label for="workField">Work Expereince</label>
                    <textarea
                        placeholder="Enter Text" 
                        class="form-control weField"
                        rows ="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="container text-center mt-2" id="weAddButton">
                        <button onclick="addNewWeField()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button>
                </div>
```